# Testing an utterance: comparison to "published" produces JSON string completely different from results obtained by querying the API

Tags: json, azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I just trained my LUIS application and published it to production.  If I test it on an utterance, I can see how that result compares to the published version and look at the JSON result.  The problem is I'm getting a completely different JSON result there than I get when I query the API via its URL.  Here is the test result JSON:

```
{
  "query": "please show me *johnson*",
  "prediction": {
    "normalizedQuery": "please show me *johnson*",
    "topIntent": "Show",
    "intents": {
      "Show": {
        "score": 0.985523641
      }
    },
    "entities": {
      "ShowObject": [
        "*johnson*"
      ],
      "$instance": {
        "ShowObject": [
          {
            "type": "ShowObject",
            "text": "*johnson*",
            "startIndex": 15,
            "length": 9,
            "score": 0.8382344,
            "modelTypeId": 1,
            "modelType": "Entity Extractor",
            "recognitionSources": [
              "model"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the API query result:

```
{
  "query": "please show me *johnson*",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "Show",
    "score": 0.985523641
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "Show",
      "score": 0.985523641
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "* johnson *",
      "type": "ShowObject",
      "startIndex": 15,
      "endIndex": 23,
      "score": 0.8382344
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem with the API query result is that it doesn't return enough information about the entity, and it returns a *different* entity than the test result.  Note above that the test result returns `*johnson*` with no spaces near the asterisks, which is how the original query is, but the API query result returns `* johnson *` with spaces near the asterisks.  I don't want it to put the spaces in, so I prefer the test result over the API query result.

Why are they different, and how do I get the API query to return a result like the test, i.e. with no modification of the input string to add spaces near the asterisks.

Here is the API query URL including parameters:

`https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/[app ID removed]?q=please+show+me+*johnson*&timezoneOffset=0&verbose=true&spellCheck=false&staging=false`

Comment: Do you need those stars? How are they getting in there in first place? markdown? Could you realistically strip them out, either before or after (e.g. regex)?

Comment: I need the stars to remain.  They're put in there by the user.  They have nothing to do with the expected LUIS behavior, but they should be left alone and not wrapped with spaces.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that in the end - I put a more complete answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see now - this is probably to represent a wildcard search, right? If so, I'm not personally aware of a way to strip this out of a LUIS response, and I've seen similar, I think, when there's an @mention in there as well. However, if this *is* to facilitate searches, such that you know there's a good chance to have a * before and/or after the "ShowObject" entity, then it should be easy enough to test for this and replace, either string or regex (replace the "star-plus-space" with a space, I mean - I realise you need the star itself). Basically, you'd replace "[start]*[space]" with "[start]*", and same at the end. Not pretty, but workable and simple to implement...

Just out of interest, do you anticipate * in the middle of a string as well?

Comment: The stars don't matter for the LUIS activity.  They might as well be another letter of the alphabet; I don't want them treated differently by LUIS.  My application does something later with them.

Comment: in that case, a regex could still be of use, if you do a start of string, and and end of string match, no? As an example, you could search for "[start][anything][space]", and trim the space? Remember, I'm only suggesting this as a possible simple workaround, because I'm not aware of a way to adjust LUIS itself to have it stop bringing back these spaces...

Comment: Well, my actual question is how I get it to produce the same results through the API call as it gets through the test utility on the site.  The test utility returns just what I'm looking for, and in general more info than the API call.

Comment: And I don't want to use regex to account for the spaces, because if a user DOES actually put spaces in, that's incorrect.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your effort, I awarded you the bounty.  If you think of anything else, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I was hoping it would be a workable solution though :-(. If I hear / think of anything else I'll come back this either way.

Comment: oh, I have thought of something else.... I didn't realise you might -want- to allow users to have spaces. If that's so, you really want the original utterance. In that case, that's what the "startIndex" and "endIndex" are supplied for - you can basically extract the entity in it's 100% original state using those, irrespective of the "recognized" entity result. Essentially, you're checking -if- a ShowObject was found, but then extracting it yourself. By the way, are you using LUISGen?

Comment: Perfect!  I had assumed those were the start and end indexes in the string with spaces around the asterisks, which now that I actually think about it doesn't make sense.  That works!  And no, I don't know what LUISGen is.  I'll have to look it up.

Comment: great, glad if I could help! LUISGen takes a saved JSON export of your LUIS model and creates a strongly typed target you can deserialize your LUIS response into - makes it easier to work with, especially for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Oh that's cool.  I've been using other online tools in the past for creating types from JSON, but I'm sure that's more specific to LUIS.

Comment: This is -kind of similar-, but only in concept - this is much more than just a C# class based on a raw JSON object. The JSON you export from LUIS includes ALL the training utterances etc. - LUISGen ignores all that, extracts just the "model" from their, and also adds methods catered for accepting a LUIS response and converting it to the right type. Check it out, well worth the bit of time (there's not too much to it) and especially for your issue I think it will help.